# Android- Calling Specific Method from ListAcitivity which invokes method in 1 of the TabActivity w/o losing TabHost

Tags: android, android-intent, android-tabhost, android-mediaplayer, android-tabactivity

### Calling Specific Method from ListActivity which invokes method in one of the Parent(TabActivity) w/o Losing TabHost Layout

I have Two Activity Inside TabHost
1.PlayingActivity
2.AlbumActivity

By Clicking Button inside AlbumActivty will jump to LIstActivity
->By clicking Item in ListActivity, I want to jump back to one of the method inside-PlayingActivity w/o Losing Tab Layout.

I can accomplish task by calling Activity n specific Method using these

## ListActivity clicking on Item invokes specific Method in PlayingActivity

```
Class SongList extends ListActivty
{
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
     //implemented list adapter-ls
      listadapter. . . .

      ls.setOnItemClickListener(New View.onItemClickListener)
        {
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) 
             {
                    int songIndex=position; 
        Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AlbumActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("methodName", "myMethod");
            i.putExtra("index", songIndex);
            startActivity(i);
              }
        }
    }

}
```

## MainActivity which host PlayingActivity & AblumActivity Under TabHost

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {

 private static final String NOW_PLAYING = "Playing";
    private static final String ALBUM = "Album";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

        // Playing Tab
        TabSpec PlayingSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(NOW_PLAYING);
        // Tab Icon
        PlayingSpec.setIndicator(NOW_PLAYING, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_now_playing));
       Intent PlayingIntent = new Intent(this, PlayingActivity.class);
        // Tab Content
        PlayingSpec.setContent(PlayingIntent);

        // Album Tab
        TabSpec AlbumSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(ALBUM);
        AlbumSpec.setIndicator(ALBUM, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_music));
        Intent AlbumIntent = new Intent(this, AlbumActivity.class);
        AlbumSpec.setContent(AlbumIntent);


        // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
        tabHost.addTab(PlayingSpec); // Adding Playing tab
        tabHost.addTab(AlbumSpec); // Adding Album tab
}
```

}

## In PlayingActivity called specific method(playSong())

```
class PlayingActivity extends Activity
{
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
    }
   protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
   super.onNewIntent(intent);
   String index=intent.getStringExtra("index");
   if(intent.getStringExtra("methodName").equals("myMethod")){
      playSong(Integer.parseInt(index));
   }
}
   private void playSong(int i)
   { 
   }
}
```

## Now the Catch iz I can somehow invokes specific Method in PlayingActivity but Playing Activity which is under TabHost loses it's TabLayout

## Is there AnyWay we can save Playing Activity to lose from it's TabLayout??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Found out that. Little bit of logic have saved my time.

Adding

```
finish();
```

inside the activity would done all my work.